# Bot returning Same welcome message again when I click on button

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am sending welcome message with two buttons when member add. But when I choose any option and click on button then bot returning same welcome message again. I am adding code. I dont know what is wrong. Please help me to resolve the issue

```
Bot information:
...............
v4sdk
channel- webchat and directline
language -node js



const { CardFactory,ActionTypes, ActivityHandler, MessageFactory } = require('botbuilder');
const { DialogBot } = require('./dialogBot');
var BotResponses = require('../constant/string');
var ConstantVariables = require('../constant/constantValue');

class DialogAndWelcomeBot extends DialogBot {
    constructor(conversationState, userState, dialog) {
        super(conversationState, userState, dialog);

        this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
            const membersAdded = context.activity.membersAdded;
            for (let cnt = 0; cnt < membersAdded.length; cnt++) {
               if (membersAdded[cnt].id !== context.activity.recipient.id) {
                            await context.sendActivity(BotResponses.GREET);
                            await context.sendActivity(BotResponses.GREET1);
                      const buttons = [
                    { type: ActionTypes.ImBack, title:ConstantVariables.SELF_ASSESSMENT , value:ConstantVariables.SELF_ASSESSMENT },
                    { type: ActionTypes.ImBack, title:ConstantVariables.sympton , value:ConstantVariables.sympton }
                    ];
                    const card = CardFactory.heroCard( '', undefined,
                     buttons, { text: 'Please select one of the categories below or type in your question.' });                     

                    await context.sendActivity({ attachments: [card] });
                   // await dialog.run(context, conversationState.createProperty('DialogState'));
                }
          }

            // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
            await next();
        });
    }
}

module.exports.DialogAndWelcomeBot = DialogAndWelcomeBot;
```

Comment: are you following any specific sample?